# Count vector occurrences java

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have two lists that contain something like that:

```
List1            List2

name.txt         145
name.txt         132
else.txt         145
name.txt         145
else.txt         145
```

I need to count how many occurrences of list2 number per file in list1:

The result should be like this:

```
145       2 occurrences in name.txt
145       2 occurrences in else.txt
132       1 occurrence in name.txt
```

How can I do this using a map?

EDIT:   I tried this using another list:

```
    ArrayList<String> newList2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=0;i<List2.size();i++)
    {
        if(List1.get(i).toLowerCase()==fileName.toLowerCase())
        {
            newErrorIDList.add(List2.get(i));
        }
    }
```

P.S.:  fileName is an outside variable that contains the file in which I want to find the occurrence of its corresponding number from list2

Comment: Post what you've tried yet ;).

Comment: I tried this with lists only, to create another list for every occurence

Comment: According to what you wrote, you need the names of the results - so what's wrong with what you did?

Comment: For large data it take a lot processing time, working with maps it's easier, I will post what I did....

Comment: I would create something what have following prototype: `Map<Integer,Map<String, Integer>> myMap;`
1st key is number from list List2, 2nd key is string with file name and integer value is number of occurrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ok to use external libs, you may use guava's MultiSet + commons' Pair:

Assuming both lists have same size:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;
import com.google.common.collect.HashMultiset;
import com.google.common.collect.Multiset;

Multiset<Pair<String, String>> set = HashMultiset.create();
for (int i = 0; i < List2.size(); i++) {
    set.add(Pair.of(List1.get(i), List2.get(i)));
}
System.out.println(set);
```

=> gives [(else.txt,145) x 2, (name.txt,132), (name.txt,145) x 2]

Comment: How to take the number of occurences directly,  using a pair as input ?

Comment: Use the "count" method from Multiset: for instance set.count(Pair.of("name.txt", "145"))